# Помогите опубликовать модуль в центральной базе данных (NPM)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Доброго время! 
Поcле команды **npm adduser** пишет:

```
Logged in as vov on https://registry.npmjs.org/.
```

и  после **npm publish**, пишет вот так:

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! You do not have permission to publish "super
module". Are you logged in as the correct user? : supermodule

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\killer\AppData\Roaming\n
pm-cache\_logs\2017-10-28T09_35_46_581Z-debug.log
```

Вот мой **package.json**

```
 {
 "name": "supermodule",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC"
 }
```

Помогите прочитать ругань

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пакет с названием [supermodule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supermodule) принадлежит пользователю [vasya](https://www.npmjs.com/~vasya) (а у вас пользователь vov, который не имеет доступ к уже существующему модулю)

Переименуйте модуль и воспользуйтесь поиском [https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=название+модуля](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F) для проверки на доступность имени.

Comment: Спасибо! Изучаю node.js , могут появиться вопросы еще